# template copy constructors inside template class

Tags: copy-constructor, template-specialization

I have template class that has some template copy constructors and it's work.
But I want to specialize copy constructor for int and can't do it.
This program prints: "CC". But need: "iC"
Help me, please.

```
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>

    template<class X> 
    class complex
    {
    public:
       complex() {}
       template<class T> complex(const complex<T>& c) {std::cout << "2";}
       template<class T> complex(const complex<T*>& c) {std::cout << "1"; }
       complex(const complex<X>& c) {std::cout << "C";}

       template<int> complex(const complex<int>& c){std::cout << "i";}
    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

       complex<int> c1;
       complex<double> c2;

       complex<int> c3(c1); //2
       complex<double> c4(c2);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With `X == int`, as in your `complex<int> c3(c1)` case (initializing a `complex<int>` from another `complex<int>`), your non-template `complex(const complex<int>& c)` will be considered a better match than your template specialization, so this is working as expected.

Try something along the lines of `complex<double> c5(c1)`, where the types don't match. In that case, the non-template constructor, since it would want a `complex<double>` argument, won't be selected as better than your specialization.

Comment: I could do it today adding new class with specialization.

        `template<class X> <br/>
        class complex
        {
        public:
 complex() {}
 template<class T> complex(const complex<T>& c) {std::cout << "2";}
 template<class T> complex(const complex<T*>& c) {std::cout << "1"; }
 complex(const complex<X>& c) {std::cout << "Base copy con" <<      std::endl;}
        };

        template<>
        class complex<int>
        {
        public:
 complex() {}
 complex(const complex<int>& c) {std::cout << "i" ;}
        };`